# How can the C++ data-oriented design achieve polymorphism without using virtual functions?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, data-oriented-design

I have found that data-oriented programming is a good way to bridge the gap between object-oriented programming and functional programming.

Data-oriented design uses data instead of objects:
https://blog.klipse.tech/dop/2022/06/22/principles-of-dop.html

However, extensibility and reuse can be a challenge. Polymorphism is the characteristic we are looking for to achieve the aforementioned.

But what does this look like in a data-oriented design world?

Comment: Static or dynamic polymorphism? But static polymorphism is not a challenge anyway, and dynamic polymorphism is avoided.

Comment: Getting rid of runtime polymorphism, rather than implementing it in a different way, is kind of the point, isn't it?

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se] or [cs.se].

Comment: I was thinking of runtime polymorphism which is where traditional OO shines. The issues brought up here are specific for C++. There is a 2019 Cppcon talk "OOP is dead, long-live data-oriented programming" which speaks about the difficulty of extensibility. Looking for solutions here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yy8jQgmhbAU&ab_channel=CppCon